# iOS TapGesture hide Touch on the same View

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

I want to do somethings on `UIImagePickerController`, I detected the view (named A) contains all the images in library. When I choose an image, I want to draw somethings on it.

I can get the image into my controller using delegate `didFinishPickMediaWithInfo` of `UiImagePickerControllerDelegate` , but I can't detect which point I tap on view A (to draw some view at this point). I tried to add `TapGestureRecognizer` to view A, it's really return for me the point but unfortunately it can't run into the delegate  `didFinishPickMediaWithInfo`, so I can't get the chosen Image.

I don't have any idea to achieve 2 things at the same time, get the chosen image on delegate `didFinishPickMediaWithInfo` and return the point I've tapped.

Are there any idea (maybe just idea) to guide me to achieve this

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank all,
Finally, I find out a solution for me to resolve this problem. It's simple and quite like cheating. I add tap gesture on UIWindow and everything go through.